# What is the best resource for learning how to handle service calls in the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, rest, soap, sdk

I'm starting out with iPhone development and am struggling to find tutorials on handling service calls whether via SOAP or REST etc. As I understand it the SDK can't handle SOAP so is it best to look into REST?

Comment: There are many questions that deal with the "SOAP vs REST" problem in iPhone development, I suggest taking a look: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+rest+soap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse XML on the iPhone, therefore nothing stops you from using SOAP services from your iPhone apps. REST services are easier to consume, though, at least in my experience. It's just a matter of using an HTTP networking library and then parsing JSON or XML responses. I personally used ASIHTTPRequest and the json-framework in many apps, with good results.

- http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/
- http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Check out other similar questions in StackOverflow for more details. There's been a lot of questions about this.

Comment: I would have to agree, I use both of those frameworks in all of my applications.  JSON is much easier to deal with as its deserialized right into dictionaries and arrays.  You don't necessarily need REST per se, as Adrian said just return JSON and you should be good.